# How to run MySQL command from C# executable to encrypt data from Hardware Sniffers?

Tags: c#, mysql, encryption

I'm making a simple C# windows executable that accesses my online SQL database.  I'm running a simple MySQL command like

```
@"SELECT * FROM " + tableName.ToString() + " WHERE COL1 LIKE '" ........
```

etc etc etc, from a MySQLConnection datatype.  The code itself is rather trivial and basically identical to the MSDN sample code.

My code accesses the DB ok, and everything is going well.  However, in my research for this, I stumbled upon articles about hardware sniffers.  I'm not a tech guru, and I don't claim to know everything, but this form of data detection is a bit disconcerting.

I'm wondering how I can encrypt the data that is being sent from my C# executable to my MySQL database, so that if someone intercepts my transmission, it will be protected.

Comment: I'm not a network admin, but that sounds like what IPSec is for. This would not happen at your application layer, it's an infrastructure concern to encrypt IP traffic on your network or subnet.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I figured this was the case, but I couldn't find any definitive information on it.